# Java, non-static cannot be reference to static context

Tags: java, static, non-static

Doing Java course, at UNI atm, and I'm having a bit of trouble with a dice-problem.

I have the following:

```
 public class Die {
   public int eyes;
   private java.util.Random r;
   private int n;

   public Die (int n) {
     r = new Random();
     this.n = n;
   }

   public void roll() {
     eyes = r.nextInt(Die.n);
   }
```

When compiling I get: non-static variable n cannot be referenced from a static context. How would I go about fixing this, whilst having it randomize from a user given value?

Comment: Take a look at this question's answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context .... Of course the question's code is a bit different and less concise, but the answers should still help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n` is not a static variable, so you cannot refer to it in a static manner (`Die.n`).

Since it is an instance variable in the `Die` class, and you are referring to it in the `Die` class, you can just use `n` instead of `Die.n`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This doesn't completely solve the problem though, seeing as I then get java.lang.NullpointerException: null, in the terminal.

Comment: How are you calling `roll()`? You should be creating a new `Die` object by using `Die die = new Die(6);` (or whatever number you want), then you would call `die.roll();`.

Comment: I'd probably also use `r.nextInt(n) + 1` otherwise you could get 0, which doesn't make sense for a die.

Comment: Added `Die die = new Die();` to the contructor, still getting nullpointer

Comment: The line `Die die = new Die();` won't compile since you do not have a no argument constructor for `Die` class.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
Die.n
```

and change it to simply

```
n
```

If `n` were declared `static`, you could use the both notations, even though the first one would be redundant (because you're from the inside of containing class)